# Struts 2 application giving HTTP Error 404 with IP Address in URL

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, struts

Hi I am making a simple struts application in eclipse. Till now it was working fine, but not when I am trying to access my home page. It is giving this error page. I have all the jars in place, mapped everything in web.xml and struts. 
When the application runs first time in machine it shows the actual url, http://localhost:8081/ProjName/jsp/view/homePage.jsp but when the page is loaded completely, the IP of my machine comes in the url instead of whole address and this 404 is shown.[see this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHPzW.png)

Comment: Please post text, not images. There's no way to help with the information provided (a 404 and a URL). Doesn't sound like an S2 issue so far, rather a machine/setup/deployment issue.

Comment: Yes it was a set up related issue.